# Test if this password is correct for current logged in user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I'm building a "change password" form for my user built with these fields:

- Old password
- New password
- Confirmation password

I need a way to check if the current logged in user password is the same as "old password" field, are there any possibility to do this, with authlogic? I can't find a method to test a password.

Comment: I don't know anything about authlogic. However, you should never be storing passwords, only salted SHA-1 (or better) hashes, correct? So you should use the same call to test if a password is correct.

Comment: I know that, that's why I'm asking this: password are hashed through authlogic in some way (which I don't know) and I would like to check my password against hashed one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Authlogic has a valid_password? method. see: http://rubydoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic/master/Authlogic/ActsAsAuthentic/Password/Methods/InstanceMethods#valid_password%3F-instance_method

So you could

```
if @user.valid_password?(params[:old_password])
  @user.password = params[:new_password]
  @user.password_confirmation = params[:new_password_confirmation]
end
```

(or similar)

Comment: +1, I was about to give the same answer. You might want to update the answer to pass the 2nd parameter set to true to check against the DB rather than the object in hand i.e. `@user.valid_password?(params[:password], true)`

Comment: @KandadaBoggu: I have a problem now, when I change the password, UserSession.find returns nil, even after a UserSession.new({...}).save, any solution?

Comment: You can find the question on this new link eventually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143656/usersession-find-returns-nil-after-changing-password