# UserSession.find returns nil after changing password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, authlogic

I recently created a way to change the current user password, however after saving the record, my UserSession.find returns nil, I tried by writing UserSession.new({...}).save with no luck, any suggestion on how to resolve this issue?

Here is my code, notice that is run through an AJAX request (this is a method under UserSessionController):

def

```
 change_my_password
    #print "--------------RECORD: #{current_user_session.record.as_json}-------- #{current_user_session.user.as_json}"
    user = current_user
    user_email = user.email
    user_remember_me = user.remember_created_at
    response = {
      :success => false,
      :message_code => Extjs::MessageCodes::ERROR,
      :message => 'Si è verificato un errore',
      :total => 0,
      :root => []
    }
    if user.valid_password?(params[:old_password], true)
      user.password = params[:new_password]
      user.password_confirmation = params[:confirm_password]
      response[:message] = 'La nuova password e la conferma non coincidono o sono troppo brevi'
      if user.save
        response[:success] = true
        response[:message_code] = Extjs::MessageCodes::SUCCESS
        response[:message] = 'Password modificata con successo'
      end
    else
      response[:message] = 'La password precedente non coincide con quella attualmente in uso'
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.extjson { render :json => response }
    end
  end
```

Comment: `record.save` only returns true or false in order to indicate whether the record was persisted or not. Consequently `@user_session` wont hold your newly created record.

Comment: @KaiKönig: Sorry I didn't get this: isn't record my User Model record? save actually returns true, so it should change the data on the database (and for subsequent login/logout, password is in fact changed). Any suggestion on how to regenerate my session in some way?

Comment: When does `UserSession.find` return nil? In subsequent calls?

Comment: @KandadaBoggu: Across 2 AJAX requests to the same route (change_my_password). First time I call it it returns the ser, the second time it returns nil :\ (only if I actually change the password, otherwise it's ok). Notice that I updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I didn't find a solution to this issue: I solved by forcing a login again after changing password (whcih is even added security, so not that bad).

I think KandadaBoggu is right with his answer, but I tested all of them and they are not working for me.

Maybe it's an issue created by something wrong in my code, I really don't know.
At the moment I just consider this as the solution because it's actually working for my software.

If a better answer is found, I would be happy to mark it.

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that you haven't set the [maintain_sessions](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/master/lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/session_maintenance.rb#L35) parameter to false, i.e.:

```
acts_as_authentic do |c|
  c.maintain_sessions = false # change this to true.
end
```

**OR**

Update the session manually after save:

```
user.send(:update_sessions)
```

**OR**

Recreate the session after the save:

```
UserSession.create(user)
```

Comment: I'm testing them but it seems that they aren't solving the issue: UserSession.create I think it destroys my session in some way, in fact the next time I call it I get user = nil. user.send(:update_sessions) same situation and with maintain_sessions explicitly set to true (in my config is not set usually), user is nil even on the first call, dunno why. I imagine I'm in a bad situation :\

Comment: Tried in that way, it's not working. Notice that my first login happens through AJAX, maybe this can create a sort of issue?

Comment: I don't think it is related to AJAX as AJAX is a regular HTTP request.  You should debug this at the client side. Also try to submit a regular request after `reset_password`. Print the session object before and after reset and in the new call.